# Java/VMs: Copying text that gets FEFF control character, occasionally creates question mark

Tags: java, swing, virtualbox

So, at my job, I've got a ticket to fix a bug that I'm not really sure is fixable. So, here's the deal:

Our application is a java Swing app that configures the under-the-hood engine that runs. All of our machines at the office are Macs, but to ensure cross-platform functionality we frequently do things in Windows VMs.

So, the guy who reported this, is working in his Windows VM using VirtualBox. He copies some text from our application in the Windows VM to our application in Mac. Our application saves its state in XML configuration files. When he then saves the changes, the text in the XML config file has a "?" character where the FEFF control character was.

Now, I've been going over our code. The paste operation drops the code into a JTable with a custom CellEditor, but the cell editor has nothing special regarding copy/paste operations. Literally no code whatsoever on that issue.

When the application then goes to write everything to the XML configuration file when it saves, it uses the org.w3c.dom.* libraries (the standard Java XML libraries) to do it. Again, can't see anything special here.

My gut says that this might not be solvable, that it might just be an issue from copying between VMs, something is getting weirdly corrupted. Anyone else ever encounter something similar or have an idea on this?

I really don't have any code samples to paste here, but anything anyone could ask for I'll try to provide.

Comment: Were you able to trace the specific point where it actually happens? Using a debugger or some ad-hoc logging or something.